# Regex подсчёт символов

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Уважаемые знатоки, есть ли в регулярных выражениях спец. сигнал, для подсчета найденных значений? Для примера на скрине, чтобы вернул 3. Подсчитать на стороне длинной строки не подходит для моего случая, интересует именно сделать это при помощи регулярок
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Длину найденного совпадения легко получить с помощью кода. Регулярные выражение помогают найти текст, но его длину они никогда не возвращают.

Comment: Подскажите, как мне забить гвоздь с помощью микроскопа. Молоток не подходит для моего случая, интересует сделать это именно с помощью микроскопа.

Comment: В случае с микроскопом всё же какой-никакой шанс есть. А тут никакого.

Comment: можно попробовать искать нужное вам словосочетание, через preg_match ($параметр поиска, $строка,)
а через strlen потом считать кол-во символов в найденных результатах.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, с помощью пайтон, например, это можно сделать так:

```
import re

result = re.search(r'Aut', 'elit Autee')
print(result.span()[1] - result.span()[0])
```

Также, так как мы находим подстроки, длина этой подстроки и будет длиной найденного вхождения:

```
import re

result = re.findall(r'aut', 'Aut gravis elit, aut simple elit', re.IGNORECASE)

for i in result:
    print(len(i))
```

А вот пример получше:

```
result = re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', '1231 12вы 12ы3 345123 65712 1ф2 45345345 234выа 234')

for i in result:
    print(len(i))
```

Сами регулярные выражения не сохраняют в себе длину. Максимум, что они содержат: начальный и конечный индексы относительно исходной строки.